# How can I SCP entire directory but exclude a directory?

Tags: centos, scp

I want to SCP an entire directory over to my new server, but exclude the thumbs/ directory inside /storage.

i want to scp over (and everything inside it, and all directories):
/storage

but exclude:
/storage/thumbs

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use rsync: rsync -av --exclude thumbs /storage dest

Rsync uses secure copy.

Comment: Actually, it pipes over SSH. But the net result is the same.

Comment: How do you rsync to another server?

Comment: Specify the destination in the form host:dir, such as `newserver:/destdir`.

Comment: +1: I was about to ask how to do `scp` recursively. I forgot about rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to be proven wrong but there's nothing I can see in the man page to suggest you can, presumably you're using '-r' right?